# Simple Slick Example Scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I was trying to practice a simple slick example with 1 table created in `Postgres`.It involves 4 files.

this is my `DAO.scala` file

```
import slick.dbio.Effect.Write
import slick.lifted.{CanBeQueryCondition, Rep, Tag}
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import slick.sql.FixedSqlAction

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.reflect._

trait BaseEntity {
  val id: Long
  val isDeleted: Boolean
}

abstract class BaseTable[E: ClassTag](tag: Tag, schemaName: Option[String], tableName: String)
  extends Table[E](tag, schemaName, tableName) {

  val classOfEntity = classTag[E].runtimeClass

  val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("Id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  val isDeleted: Rep[Boolean] = column[Boolean]("IsDeleted", O.Default(false))
}

trait BaseRepositoryComponent[T <: BaseTable[E], E <: BaseEntity] {
  def getById(id: Long): Future[Option[E]]

  def getAll: Future[Seq[E]]

  def filter[C <: Rep[_]](expr: T => C)(implicit wt: CanBeQueryCondition[C]): Future[Seq[E]]

  def save(row: E): Future[E]

  def deleteById(id: Long): Future[Int]

  def updateById(id: Long, row: E): Future[Int]
}

trait BaseRepositoryQuery[T <: BaseTable[E], E <: BaseEntity] {

   val query: slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api.type#TableQuery[T]

  def getByIdQuery(id: Long): Query[T, E, Seq] = {
    query.filter(_.id === id).filter(_.isDeleted === false)
  }

  def getAllQuery: Query[T, E, Seq] = {
    query.filter(_.isDeleted === false)
  }

  def filterQuery[C <: Rep[_]](expr: T => C)(implicit wt:     CanBeQueryCondition[C]): Query[T, E, Seq] = {
    query.filter(expr).filter(_.isDeleted === false)
  }

  def saveQuery(row: E): FixedSqlAction[E, NoStream, Write] = {
    query returning query += row
  }

  def deleteByIdQuery(id: Long): FixedSqlAction[Int, NoStream, Write]={
query.filter(_.id === id).map(_.isDeleted).update(true)
  }

  def updateByIdQuery(id: Long, row: E): FixedSqlAction[Int, NoStream, Write] = {
    query.filter(_.id === id).filter(_.isDeleted === false).update(row)
  }

}

abstract class BaseRepository[T <: BaseTable[E], E <: BaseEntity :    ClassTag](clazz: TableQuery[T])
  extends BaseRepositoryQuery[T, E]
 with BaseRepositoryComponent[T, E] {
   val clazzTable: TableQuery[T] = clazz
  lazy val clazzEntity = classTag[E].runtimeClass
  val query: slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api.type#TableQuery[T] = clazz
  val user = "postgres"
  val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/learning"
  val password = "admin"
 val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"


  val db = Database.forURL(url, user = user, password = password, driver = driver)

  def getAll: Future[Seq[E]] = {
    db.run(getAllQuery.result)
  }

  def getById(id: Long): Future[Option[E]] = {
    db.run(getByIdQuery(id).result.headOption)
  }

  def filter[C <: Rep[_]](expr: T => C)(implicit wt: CanBeQueryCondition[C]): Future[Seq[E]] = {
db.run(filterQuery(expr).result)
  }

  def save(row: E): Future[E] = {
    db.run(saveQuery(row))
  }

  def updateById(id: Long, row: E): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(updateByIdQuery(id, row))
  }

 def deleteById(id: Long): Future[Int] = {
    db.run(deleteByIdQuery(id))
  }

}
```

this is my `entities.scala` file

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import slick.lifted.ProvenShape.proveShapeOf
import slick.lifted.{Rep, Tag}

class EmployeeTable(_tableTag: Tag) extends BaseTable[Employee]    (_tableTag, Some("learning"), "Employee") {

  def * = (id, firstName, isDeleted) <>(Employee.tupled,     Employee.unapply)

  def ? = (Rep.Some(id), Rep.Some(firstName),    Rep.Some(isDeleted)).shaped.<>({ r => import r._; _1.map(_ => Employee.tupled((_1.get, _2.get, _3.get))) }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

  override val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("EmployeeId", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  val firstName: Rep[String] = column[String]("FirstName")
  override val isDeleted: Rep[Boolean] = column[Boolean]("IsDeleted")
  lazy val employeeTable = new TableQuery(tag => new EmployeeTable(tag))

}


case class Employee(id: Long, firstName: String, isDeleted: Boolean)     extends BaseEntity
```

this is my `build.scala` file.

```
name := "SlickAkka"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "3.2.0-M1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
)
```

and finally my `EmployeeRepository.scala` file

```
import slick.lifted.TableQuery
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
abstract class EmployeeRepository
 extends  BaseRepository[EmployeeTable, Employee](TableQuery[EmployeeTable]){

   def insertItem(row: Employee) = {
       super.save(row)
   }

}

object ImplEmployeeRepository extends EmployeeRepository

object TestEmp extends App {

  val emp = Employee(0L, "aamir", false)

  for {
    result <- ImplEmployeeRepository.insertItem(emp)
    _ = println(result)
  } yield result
  Thread.sleep(5000)

}
```

as soon as I run 'TestEmp' object it throws this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
>       at slick.ast.ColumnOption$PrimaryKey$.(ColumnOption.scala:15)
>       at slick.ast.ColumnOption$PrimaryKey$.(ColumnOption.scala)
>       at slick.relational.RelationalTableComponent$ColumnOptions$class.$init$(RelationalProfile.scala:110)
>       at slick.relational.RelationalTableComponent$$anon$2.(RelationalProfile.scala:116)
>       at slick.relational.RelationalTableComponent$class.$init$(RelationalProfile.scala:116)
>       at slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$.(PostgresProfile.scala:245)
>       at slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$.(PostgresProfile.scala)
>       at BaseRepository.(DAO.scala:78)
>       at EmployeeRepository.(EmployeeRepository.scala:3)
>       at ImplEmployeeRepository$.(EmployeeRepository.scala:11)
>       at ImplEmployeeRepository$.(EmployeeRepository.scala)
>       at TestEmp$.delayedEndpoint$TestEmp$1(EmployeeRepository.scala:18)
>       at TestEmp$delayedInit$body.apply(EmployeeRepository.scala:13)
>       at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>       at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
>       at scala.App$$Lambda$5/305808283.apply(Unknown Source)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:378)
>       at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
>       at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
>       at TestEmp$.main(EmployeeRepository.scala:13)
>       at TestEmp.main(EmployeeRepository.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 26 more

I can't figure out what is the issue exactly??

Comment: Looks like you're using the 2.11 build of slick, while your scala version is set to 2.12. Not sure that's the issue but that doesn't look good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Scala compiler version is `2.12` but your slick version is `2.11`.

Change the slick version to `2.12` or Change the Scala compiler version to `2.11`

```
name := "SlickAkka"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "3.2.0-M1", //error is here
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
)
```

Changed correct build.sbt

```
name := "SlickAkka"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "3.2.0-M1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
)
```

or

```
name := "SlickAkka"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0-M1", //notice double %%
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
)
```

or With Scala compiler `2.12`

```
name := "SlickAkka"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0-M1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
)
```

or Scala compiler `2.12`

```
name := "SlickAkka"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.12" % "3.2.0-M1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
)
```